# input a value before running cmd?

Tags: cmd

In no scripter at all, but was wondering on how to make a command file (.cmd) where i can input a value or preferably choose from a menu when executing the file.

the start.cmd file runs the program "minerd" with the arguments showen:

```
minerd -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://us-east.multipool.us:3357 -O user:pass -q
```

The one thing i would like to chose from a menu is the port number. The port number determines what crypto currency i would like to mine.

here is some as an example:

```
Multipool:7777 
DigitalCoin (DGC):3343 
NovaCoin (NVC):3344 
LuckyCoin (LKY):3345 
Argentum (ARG):3346 
PhenixCoin (PXC):3347 
and more....
```

it would be nice to have the menu show the name of the currency instead of the port number. But that is not a must.

What would be the best way to do this?

Regards

Comment: If you provide a full list then you can get a working solution.

Comment: That is so cool, thanks man, i have just added the rest my self, now that i have a base script i can see what more i can do, again thanks :)

Comment: Just a little thing more, i now use 2 .cmd files one for the url shown and one for another url. can i also add a that url in there somewhere? that url dont have an option with ports, its a single site for one crypt coin only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this as miner.bat and run it: (extra option added for single URL)

```
@:Single URL:0000
@:Multipool:7777 
@:DigitalCoin (DGC):3343 
@:NovaCoin (NVC):3344 
@:LuckyCoin (LKY):3345 
@:Argentum (ARG):3346 
@:PhenixCoin (PXC):3347 
@echo off
:start
set "var=@"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:@" %%a in ('findstr /n "%var%:" "%~f0" ') do (
echo %%a %%b
)
echo.
set /p "num=Select a number: "
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:@" %%a in ('findstr /n "%var%:" "%~f0" ^|findstr "^%num%:" ') do (
set "name=%%b"
set "port=%%c"
)
echo starting %name%:%port%
title Mining "%name%"
if %port% EQU 0000 (
   minerd -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://specialURLhere -O user:pass -q
  ) else (
   minerd -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://us-east.multipool.us:%port% -O user:pass -q
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i just have to learn this me own self, hehehe

Comment: Now that i have multiple choices from the same file, it would be really helpful to have the cmd window "title" show what i'm actually mining, would that be possible? Im thinking like having the chosen menu item in the title of the window in addition tho the shortcut name.

Comment: Try it now. :)  There is a title command if the tool runs in a cmd window.  The shortcut name is not as easily processed.

Comment: Yeah, the tool runs in a cmd window, but im happy awesome script mahn. thank you so much bra...